# How to add data from instagram api to existing user record?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I associate data returned from instagram API with an existing user account--so that the instagram profile info can be stored in the same document as the user that made the request?

I'm using node.js, Mongoose with MongoDB, and node-instagram from npm to pull in basic user info from instagram. Users on this site will create an account and then later click a button to connect their account to instagram. I'm able to pull in instagram data and store it on my database but I'm not sure how to associate this data with the local (already existing) account that made the request?

```
    app.get('/auth/instagram/feed', async (req, res) => {
     try {
     const data = await instagram.authorizeUser(req.query.code, 
    redirectUri);


    const newUserInfo = new User({
      username: data.user.username,
      full_name: data.user.full_name,
      access_token: data.access_token,
    });

    newUserInfo.save();
    res.redirect("/");
   } catch (err) {
     res.json(err);
   }
    });
```

This successfully stores some basic instagram info on the database. Instead of saving a new record, how do I add this data to an existing user's record with email and password info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by just creating a variable before the await line that gets the user id.

I've added my full code below as well as I neglected to include everything in my original post. Please note that the "/auth/instagram/feed" route is called by instagram (if you are confused about where that is coming from). You have to enter this into their URI redirect when signing up for a new API app.

```
const instagram = new instagramConnect({
  clientId: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET
});

const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram/feed';


app.get("/instagram-connect", function(req, res){
  res.render("instagramConnect");
});

app.get('/auth/instagram', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(instagram.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUri, { scope: ['basic'] }));
});


app.get('/auth/instagram/feed', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userID = req.user._id;
    const data = await instagram.authorizeUser(req.query.code, redirectUri);
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userID}, {access_token: data.access_token}, function(err){
      if(!err){
        res.redirect("/ig-success");
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json(err);
     }
  });
```